# Query Parameter disappearing from URL

Tags: file-upload, url, query, edit

I'm currently working on a document management system (SP 2010) and I have one last hurdle to get over before completion.

I have an `Upload Link` which is a hyperlink that opens a document library upload.aspx form.  I'm adding a parameter in the URL called `DocID`.  When the user clicks the `Upload` link, the standard upload.aspx form will open, the user will select the document, and click `Ok`.  At this point the Edit.aspx form will open and allow for metadata to be entered.  I'm trying to auto populate a field in the Edit form called `DocID`.

For some reason, the transition from the upload form to the edit form is causing the query parameter to be deleted/removed.

The Upload Link is: `/Upload.aspx?DocID=3&List={8643ECCE-CAB9-4B8B-A003-093DE76B68E9}&RootFolder=`

When you click `Ok` on the upload form, the edit form opens and the `DocID=3` is completely missing.

The Edit form URL: `/Forms/Edit.aspx?Mode=Upload&ID=5&RootFolder=foldername` (No `DocID=3` present)

When I add the `DocID=3` into the Edit form URL and refresh the browser, the field is auto populating as it should.